# Where is the mistake in the convolution?

Tags: discrete-signals, convolution

Let :
$$
x[n]=\begin{cases}
1&\text{if $0\leq n\leq 4$}\\ \\
0&\text{if otherwise}
\end{cases}
\qquad
\text{and}
\qquad
h[n]=\begin{cases}
\alpha^{n}&\text{if $0\leq n\leq 6$}\\ \\
0&\text{if otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
We must compute the convolution :
$$
(x*h)[n]=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}x[k]h[n-k]
$$
Observe that $x[n]=u[n]$ for $n\in[0,4]$ and $0$ otherwise. Furthermore, $h[n]=\alpha^{n}u[n]$ for $n\in[0,6]$. Thus :
\begin{array}{c | c c c c c c c }
\mathbf{x} & 1 & \alpha & \alpha^{2} & \alpha^{3} &\alpha^{4} &\alpha^{5} &\alpha^{6}\\   
\hline 
1 & 1 & \alpha & \alpha^{2} & \alpha^{3} &\alpha^{4} &\alpha^{5} &\alpha^{6}\\  
1 & 1 & \alpha & \alpha^{2} & \alpha^{3} &\alpha^{4} &\alpha^{5} &\alpha^{6}\\    
1 & 1 & \alpha & \alpha^{2} & \alpha^{3} &\alpha^{4} &\alpha^{5} &\alpha^{6}\\    
1 & 1 & \alpha & \alpha^{2} & \alpha^{3} &\alpha^{4} &\alpha^{5} &\alpha^{6}\\  
1 & 1 & \alpha & \alpha^{2} & \alpha^{3} &\alpha^{4} &\alpha^{5} &\alpha^{6}\\     
0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0& 0 & 0 & 0 \\  
0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0& 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\begin{align*}
\displaystyle (x*h)[n]&=\left[\sum_{k=0}^{0}\alpha^{k}\;,\;\sum_{k=0}^{1}\alpha^{k}\;,\;\cdots\;,\;\sum_{k=0}^{4}\alpha^{k}\;,\;\sum_{k=1}^{5}\alpha^{k}\;,\;\sum_{k=2}^{6}\alpha^{k}\;,\;\cdots\;,\;\sum_{k=5}^{6}\alpha^{k}\;,\;\sum_{k=6}^{6}\alpha^{k}\right]\\ \\
&=\begin{cases}
\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n}\alpha^{k}&\text{if $0\leq n\leq 4$}\\
\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}\alpha^{k}&\text{if $n=5$}\\
\displaystyle\sum_{k=n+2}^{6}\alpha^{k}&\text{if $0\leq n\leq4$}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
I wish to know where my mistake is and how to fix it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$3^{rd}$ term in your final answer should have $6 \le n \le 10$, instead of $0 \le n \le 4$. And, the limit of summation will go from $n-4$ to $6$.

$$\sum^{6}_{k = n-4} \alpha^k \ ,  6 \le n \le 10$$

$0 \le n \le 4$ case has already been covered by the $1^{st}$ term of final answer.